# Domain controller with HyperV

Tags: performance, hyper-v, domaincontroller

just a question, is a good idea to host machines with HyperV on a DC?

This is my Idea.

if the answer is no, can you explain why?

Thanks
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question doesn't seem to be related to programming in any way and should hence be considered off topic for SO. Server Fault would probably be a more suitable place for (the question is somewhat old by now as well and you might already have found the info you need but I've flagged it for the moderators to perhaps consider a move from SO to SF or have it closed altogether).

Secondly, as for your question;
Generally no, it's not a good idea but there could be ifs and buts to everything I guess.

For a smaller company with perhaps only the one existing server (and no budget to add machines or get professional help to make any bigger changes to their current setup) which also happenes to be their DC, I guess it all comes down to what kind of workload the DC is under to begin with and just what will be hosted in Hyper-V. I'd personally still recommend against it though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea as it's not a supported scenario from MS. I don't even know if server manager lets you install both.

You can host a VM with AD, but depending on your setup (cluster/HyperV in domain or not, ...) you really should add an AD physical server (even a very small one) for hyper-V to authenticate his services against when your AD VM has not started. It can save you a lot of time...